# How can I refresh an adapter from an onClick event in Android

Tags: android

I have a ArrayAdapter onto which each row has a button which deletes the data associated to the row.  So onClick for the "on row delete button" how do I delete the row from the display?  I believe I need to refresh the parent view?

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    deleteThisRowFromDB();
    //ok now how do I delete this row from the ArrayAdapter display?

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call `notifyDataSetChanged()` method for refreshing data. You might need to override the method as below,

```
@Override
public void notifyDataSetChanged() 
{
    super.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

update the database with deleting the data,
set `notify` to Adapter by using the method:

`adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the simple cursor adapter to bind data to the listview or (parent view)... whenever you delete data from database cursor adapter will updates itself automatically

FYI
[Check this example](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/09/simplecursoradapters-and-listviews/)